# Call to undefined method App\Product::getProductStock()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

> BadMethodCallException
>   Call to undefined method App\Product::getProductStock()
>   This error occurred while accessing the model function in controller

My `Controller`

```php
            $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $user_email = Auth::user()->email;


            // To prevent out of stock material from ordering
            $userCart=DB::table('cart')->where('user_email',$user_email)->get();
            // echo "<pre>"; print_r($userCart); die;
            foreach ($userCart as $cart) {

                $product_stock= Product:: getProductStock($cart->product_id,$cart->size);
                echo $product_stock;

                if ($product_stock==0) {
                    return redirect('/cart')->with('flash_message_error','Product is Stock sold out. Buy another product');
                }

                if ($Cart->quantity>$product_stock) {
                    return redirect('/cart')->with('flash_message_error','Reduced product stock & Try Again');
                }

            }
```

`Model`

```php
    public static function getProductStock($product_id,$product_size)
    {
        $getProductStock=ProductsAttribute::select('stock')->where(['product_id'=>$product_id,'size'=>$product_size])->first();
        return $getProductStock->stock;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you product retrieving approach is not the best.

To get the product you should use this approach:

```
$product = Product::find($cart->product_id);
```

And to retrieve the stock should be:

```
$product_stock = $product->getProductStock($product->id, $cart->size);
```